# Escape sequence to perform CRLF but only when not in the beginning of line?

Tags: shell, xterm

I have an interactive application via tty in raw mode. When I exit it, I want shell prompt to start on a new line. There should be some escape sequence which causes a terminal to do CR + LF but only when cursor is not already in the beginning of line. Which is that escape sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You could test for cursor position, the following will give you the horizontal cursor position:

```bsh
IFS=';' read -sdR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL;echo "${COL#*[}"
```

and then in a script for example you could do

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

x_pos=$(IFS=';' read -sdR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL;echo "${COL#*[}")   

if [ $x_pos == 1 ] 
 then
   echo "We are at the beginning since cursor is at $x_pos"
else 
    echo "Cursor is at $x_pos so send $LF with \n" 
fi
```

Comment: This method uses sending escape sequence to terminal **and** reading a reply from the terminal. I would like to avoid using this method because there is a potential problem with it. I would like to find a way to do this in one step: just send an escape sequence to the terminal and terminal will check cursor position and decide if it needs to put CRLF itself. I'm sure this situation is common enough that there should be a special escape sequence for it.